MongoDB Error: Cast to [string] failed for value... when removing value in an array
I'm using MongoDB for the first time.
In my current project, an inventory management app, I'm trying to implement a feature that whenever the user loans an item, the LENT status is added to the item status array. If the item is returned, then the LENT status should be removed from the array.
Now I'm currently facing the error:
"error": "Cast to [string] failed for value \"[ { '$pull': { 'itemDetails.itemStatus': 'Lent' } } ]\" (type string) at path \"itemDetails.itemStatus.0\" because of \"CastError\""

I'm lost to as why this is happening? Any help or insights is really appreciated.
Schema
>   itemStatus: [{
>     type: String,
>     enum: ["Missing", "Damaged", "Lent", "In Storage"],
>     required: true,   }],

Controller Partial Code:
Adding Lent
  await inventoryModel.findByIdAndUpdate(itemId, {
      $set: {
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.stockStatus" : getStockStatus(newCurrentQuantity, max, min),
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.currentQuantity": newCurrentQuantity,
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.pendingQuantity": newPendingQuantity,
        "itemDetails.itemStatus" : lentExists
        ? item.itemDetails.itemStatus
        : [...item.itemDetails.itemStatus, "Lent"]
      },
    });

Removing Lent
 await inventoryModel.findByIdAndUpdate(itemId, {
      $set: {
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.stockStatus" : getStockStatus(newCurrentQuantity, max, min),
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.currentQuantity": newCurrentQuantity,
        "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.pendingQuantity": newPendingQuantity,
        "itemDetails.itemStatus": lentExists && newPendingQuantity === 0
          ? { $pull: { "itemDetails.itemStatus": "Lent" } }
          : item.itemDetails.itemStatus
      },
    });


itemStatus is an array of enum strings as opposed to just one string which doesn't sound like a good design. Nevertheless, the problem is that $set is one update operator, you can't use $pull inside it. You can have both inside the same update object just not $pull nested in $set. Your code is trying to set itemStatus to the value { $pull: { "itemDetails.itemStatus": "Lent" } } which is interpreted as a string and that string is not one of your enum values.

Can you suggest other design decision for the itemStatus?
Any would be appreciated.

It depends on your design. If you were tracking the status of an item over a period of time then storing itemStatus as an array of objects consisting of a timestamp and a status might be suitable but it sounds like an item is either Missing, Damaged, Lent or In Storage so I would imagine it can't be all of those things at the same time so just having itemStatus as a simple string would work and would save you having to manage an array.

You can try this:
Adding Lent
const update = {
   $set: {
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.stockStatus" : getStockStatus(newCurrentQuantity, max, min),
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.currentQuantity": newCurrentQuantity,
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.pendingQuantity": newPendingQuantity
   }
}
if(lentExists){
   update.$set["itemDetails.itemStatus"] = item.itemDetails.itemStatus
}else{
   update.$push = {"itemDetails.itemStatus": "Lent"}
}
await inventoryModel.findByIdAndUpdate(itemId, update);

Removing Lent
const update = {
   $set: {
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.stockStatus" : getStockStatus(newCurrentQuantity, max, min),
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.currentQuantity": newCurrentQuantity,
      "itemDetails.stockDetails.quantity.pendingQuantity": newPendingQuantity
   }
}
if(lentExists && newPendingQuantity === 0){
   update.$pull = {"itemDetails.itemStatus": "Lent"}
}else{
   update.$set["itemDetails.itemStatus"] = item.itemDetails.itemStatus
}
await inventoryModel.findByIdAndUpdate(itemId, update);


